# I can't view index page

Tags: web-hosting

Just to try I had uploaded worpress on my working website and then couple of days later I deleted wordpress files.(on ftp delete wordpress...)

Now as I want to view the home page I get: "The requested URL / was not found on this server."
though I got this as index.html on the server.

Actually I can't view any item(images,other pages..) that is on server uploaded

Where should I look to fix this?
Thnx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You probably still have an .htaccess file, which will attempt to use Wordpress's index.php for any URL on your site. Try deleting the .htaccess file.

Comment: there is one .htaccess file(which i have just deleted) in cgi-data but not on home directory.. but doesn't change anything..

Comment: To clarify, you have an index.html on the public_html (or equivalent) directory?

Comment: It could be anything. We don't have much information to help you. If you don't know what other information is relevant, you probably need help debugging. Try Freenode.net? You might also want to try SuperUser.com.

Comment: Indeed, I can't see anything relevant to this point. I check these websites then maybe mailing my hosting.. thnx anyway1